# What does the Angular2 "BrowserDomAdapter" do?

Tags: angular

It is currently undocumented on the site:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an abstraction of the DOM. It was mentioned several times that it is not intended to be used except internally in Angular2.

Because developers try to avoid direct DOM access they still use `BrowserDomAdapter` to get abstraction from the DOM to keep the code compatible with server-side rendering and with WebWorkers. Some official statement about whether to use it or what to use instead is still missing as far as I know. I think there are plans to provide "some" abstraction that is intended to be used outside Angular itself but it has yet to be carved out how that will look like (`BrowserDomAdapter` or something else).